# inserting new columns in a table and update those columns from row 1

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have inserted a new column in a table.

```
alter table patient add (address varchar2(50));
```

Now the existing table looks like:

```
p_id   p_name
--------------
r11    roy
s33    sahu
```

After adding new column I want to update the column with data so that it looks like following:

```
p_id  p_name  address
----------------------
r11   roy     delhi
s33   sahu    kanpur
```

What is the query that I have to run for this?

Comment: Depends on the source of the addresses. The simplest version is to update one row at a time using "update patient set address = (value) where p_id = 'r11'".

Comment: thanks a lot.my table is updated easily.

Comment: How many rows your table have?

Comment: until now there are 10 rows

Comment: Okay seems you are done with updates

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is the simplest thing you can do and shows a total lack of effort.